# Chrome Extensions, Passing Large Variables to Other Windows via php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, google-chrome

I'm currently writing a Chrome Extension that takes user selected data and passes it to another window.  Aside from the manifest.json files, I have a background.js and index.php file.

The background.js file successfully grabs the user selected data, opens a new broswer window, and then passes the user selected data to the index.php file located on a server via $_GET.  This works great until you exceed a certain character limit in which case  you get an error saying the url is too long.  I was wondering if there was anyway to send the data from the background.js file to the new window using $_POST or any other method that would allow larger data selections?  Or could I just pass the user selected data to the new window first, and then have that window access the server?

background.js

```
function getClickHandler() {
  return function(info, tab) {

      var tx =  info.selectionText;
      tx = encodeURIComponent(tx);

    // Create a new window to the info page.
      var url = 'http://192.168.0.22?tx=' + tx;

    chrome.windows.create({url: url, width: 500, height: 760 });
  };
};


chrome.contextMenus.create({
  "title" : "Store",
  "type" : "normal",
  "contexts" : ["selection"],
  "onclick" : getClickHandler()
});
```

index.php

```
<?php 

$text = $_GET['tx'];
print ($text);

?>
```

Comment: Maybe create a form with a `textarea`, populate that `textarea`, and then submit the form to a new window? I say `maybe` because I don't have experience with Chrome Extensions...

Comment: That's a good idea.  The problem is my java is really limited, and I wouldn't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Potentially you could create a form dynamically and then set an input to the value you're trying to send as a query-string-parameter.

Something like:

```
var $form  = $('<form action="' + url + '" method="POST" target="_blank" />'),
    $input = $('<input name="tx" type="text" />').val(tx);

$form.append($input).trigger("submit");
```

Without running the code I'm not sure if the `submit` will function without adding the form to the DOM, if not then you'll need to append the form to the DOM and then trigger `submit`, after which you probably want to remove the form from the DOM.

I say *potentially* because I'm not familiar with writing Chrome Extensions but I've done this as part of a normal web-app before and it worked.